# Infnite nested ideals in Z

Tags: ring-theory

Is there an example of infinitely nested ideals $I_1 \subset I_2 \subset I_3 \ldots$ of the ring $\mathbb Z$? And if it is not possible how might one prove this?

Answer (score 1):

Every ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$ is principal. Moreover, it is easy to see that $(a) \subseteq (b)$ iff $b \mid a$. Since every number has only finitely many divisors, there can't be infinitely nested ideals.

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb Z$ all prime ideals are maximal. Since $\mathbb Z$ is a principal ideal domain, suppose $I=(n)$ and $J=(m)$.  Now, $I\supseteq J$ if and only if $n|m$.  I assume you're referring to proper ideals.

Comment: So what is wrong with $2\mathbb Z$, $4 \mathbb Z$ etc.?

Comment: Well those are descending. $2\mathbb Z\supseteq 4\mathbb Z\supseteq\ldots$.  Your question is looking for a sequence in which the inclusion is in the other direction.

Comment: Oh yes, good point. Thanks